# $gp, .cpload and position independence on MIPS

Tags: linux, assembly, mips

I'm reading about PIC implementation on MIPS on Linux [here](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code). It says:

> The global pointer which is stored in the $gp register (aka $28) is a callee saved register.

The [Wikipedia article about MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_register_usage) says the same.

However, according to them, when a `.cpload` directive is being used in function prologue, it clobbers the previous value of $gp without saving it first. When a `.cprestore` is used, it saves the *current* $gp to the stack frame, as opposed to the value of $gp that was there on function entrance. Same goes for the effect `.cprestore` has on `jal`/`jalr`: it restores $gp once the callee returns - assuming the callee might've clobbered it.

And finally, there's nothing in the function epilogue about $gp.

All in all, doesn't sound like a callee-saved register to me. Sounds like a caller-saved register. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux programs on MIPS can be compiled as pic or not. If compiled as pic, then they must use "abicalls", and its behaviour is a little different from that of the no-abicalls convention.

From the "section Position-Independent Function Prologue" of the "SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE - MIPS Processor Supplement 3rd Edition" we can cite:

> After calculating the gp, a function allocates the local stack space and saves the gp on the stack, so it can be restored after subsequent function calls. In other words, the gp is a caller saved register.
>
> The code in the following figure illustrates a position-independent function prologue. _gp_disp represents the offset between the beginning of the function and the global offset table.
>
> ```
> name:
>    la gp, _gp_disp
>    addu gp, gp, t9
>    addiu sp, sp, –64
>    sw gp, 32(sp)
> ```

So in summary, if you're using `-mabicalls` then `gp` is calculated at the beginning of all the functions needing global symbols (with some exceptions), and additionally any code (abi or not) that calls abi code will ensure that the called function address is stored in `t9`.

Comment: So, basically, the Linux/MIPS ABI flouts the vendor suggested convention :) Cool.